# hadoop CompositeInputFormat not joining all data

Tags: java, input, hadoop, mapreduce

I'm currently working with Hadoop 0.20.2 and the old API. What I want to do a map-side join. I have a graph dataset which consist of two files one with edges and the other with nodes. The edges are in the format "target source label" and the nodes are "nodeID '-' label 0" and sorted on the first value.

Everything is working fine with small toy examples (6 nodes and 8 edges) but when I scale things up it only joins the first part of the input files. I cannot find the reason for this, because everything should be in the correct format and sorted. Am I missing something?

For 'debugging' I just printed the key with the values in the TupleWritable indented at the map. It can be seen here, http://pastebin.com/rcNx2r5c .

The nodes file is 9416 bytes and the edge file 15797 bytes and are fully outputted in the result. But after key 98 the join stops. It then outputs first the edges and then the nodes, however both node and edge with key 99 are there.

My job setting for the CompositeInputFormat:

```
conf.setInputFormat(CompositeInputFormat.class);

Path[] input = new Path[] { inputNodes, inputEdges};
conf.set("key.value.separator.in.input.line", "\t");
conf.set("mapred.join.expr", CompositeInputFormat.compose(
   "outer", KeyValueTextInputFormat.class,
   input )
);
```

Any help would be appreciated, so thanks in advance!

**EDIT**: I have solved the problem. For those interested; Problem was the KeyValueTextInputFormat. It has key and value both as Text where I should have had LongWritable key and Text value. While I thought this would not be a problem, it seems to fail on this. So I made my own input format based on KeyValueTextInputFormat.

```
public class KeyValueLongInputFormat extends FileInputFormat<LongWritable, Text> implements JobConfigurable {

    private CompressionCodecFactory compressionCodecs = null;

    @Override
    public void configure(JobConf conf) {
        compressionCodecs = new CompressionCodecFactory(conf);
    }

    protected boolean isSplitable(FileSystem fs, Path file) {
        return compressionCodecs.getCodec(file) == null;
    }

    @Override
    public RecordReader<LongWritable, Text> getRecordReader(InputSplit genericSplit, JobConf job, Reporter reporter)
            throws IOException {

        reporter.setStatus(genericSplit.toString());
        return new KeyValueLongLineRecordReader(job, (FileSplit) genericSplit);
    }

}
```

and

```
public class KeyValueLongLineRecordReader implements RecordReader<LongWritable, Text> {
    private final LineRecordReader lineRecordReader;

    private byte separator = (byte) '\t';

    private LongWritable dummyKey;

    private Text innerValue;

    public Class getKeyClass() {
        return LongWritable.class;
    }

    public LongWritable createKey() {
        return new LongWritable();
    }

    public Text createValue() {
        return new Text();
    }

    public KeyValueLongLineRecordReader(Configuration job, FileSplit split) throws IOException {

        lineRecordReader = new LineRecordReader(job, split);
        dummyKey = lineRecordReader.createKey();
        innerValue = lineRecordReader.createValue();
        String sepStr = job.get("key.value.separator.in.input.line", "\t");
        this.separator = (byte) sepStr.charAt(0);
    }

    public static int findSeparator(byte[] utf, int start, int length, byte sep) {
        for (int i = start; i < (start + length); i++) {
            if (utf[i] == sep) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    /** Read key/value pair in a line. */
    public synchronized boolean next(LongWritable key, Text value) throws IOException {
        LongWritable tKey = key;
        Text tValue = value;
        byte[] line = null;
        int lineLen = -1;
        if (lineRecordReader.next(dummyKey, innerValue)) {
            line = innerValue.getBytes();
            lineLen = innerValue.getLength();
        } else {
            return false;
        }
        if (line == null)
            return false;
        int pos = findSeparator(line, 0, lineLen, this.separator);
        if (pos == -1) {
            tKey.set(Long.valueOf(new String(line, 0, lineLen)));
            tValue.set("");
        } else {
            int keyLen = pos;
            byte[] keyBytes = new byte[keyLen];
            System.arraycopy(line, 0, keyBytes, 0, keyLen);
            int valLen = lineLen - keyLen - 1;
            byte[] valBytes = new byte[valLen];
            System.arraycopy(line, pos + 1, valBytes, 0, valLen);
            tKey.set(Long.valueOf(new String(keyBytes)));
            tValue.set(valBytes);
        }
        return true;
    }

    public float getProgress() {
        return lineRecordReader.getProgress();
    }

    public synchronized long getPos() throws IOException {
        return lineRecordReader.getPos();
    }

    public synchronized void close() throws IOException {
        lineRecordReader.close();
    }
}
```

Fixed my problem.

Comment: I think it is fair game to add a separate answer and accept it as correct if you solve your own problem. :) It explicitly shows that a question is answered, helping both people looking for answers and those wanting to help answer.